# Python Script for browsing through a website - Cant login

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to log in via a Python script to a website and do some operations there. The process will be:

1. Login to the website.
2. Press a specific button to get forwarded to the new page.
3. Get specific data from the forwarded page and do operations like putting values in fields and press the save button.

My problem is, I can't get access to the website.

The error message in PyCharm(IDE):

```
<div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>The credentials provided do not authorize you to view this directory or page.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
```

I linked an image with the wanted website login form:
[Login window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfD6Z.png).

I am unsure if I need a http/s request or if it's done with JavaScript because I have no knowledge about both.
I can reach some kind of success with this:
[Result on main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58EKv.png).

But it's just giving me like 10% of the information I need. Since it's also hard to visualize, I can't really tell if it is the site I expected.

I have used the requests module for this:

```
user_name = file[0]
password = file[1]
login_url = r"https://.../..."

response = requests.get(login_url,
                    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user_name, password))

print(response.text)
```

What I have used:

- PyCharm IDE
- Python module Requests
- The wanted website

I also tried to get it to work with the mechanize module. But I could not even login into the website at all.

Comment: First all of you  should  check that username and password is correct or not because error is simply  showing that you have wrong credential. so  do manual login to website  with open google chrome network see there is `GET` request or `post`, what are headers , there are  cookies or not like this then implement in python.

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)